# Network Routing and what makes network loop free

Tags: routing, network-core

I came across this question and I have no clue how to prove. Any help would be appreciated.

Q) Prove that a shortest path across a graph is loop free

Comment: Different protocols use different methods to make sure that paths are loop-free. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Loops mean there will be more hops. QED (A-B-C-B-D is more hops than A-B-D)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By contradiction: Suppose *p* is the shortest path across the graph and *p* has a loop. Remove the loop. The new loop-less path across the graph is shorter than *p*. We have achieved a contradiction, so our initial supposition must be false.

(This applies only if "shortest" means "smallest sum of edge weights" and there are no negative edge weights.)